# Assumptions made on probability spaces in a statistical setting

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

In statistics, when we assume we have a true probability space we are trying to understand the distribution of, do we assume anything about the sigma-algebra? Namely do we assume that it is a topological space and we can therefore define a Borel sigma-algebra? Or do we assume that it is countable/uncountable? I assume we must assume we have some true probability space that we are trying to estimate the distribution of. But what technical assumptions are made on this space?

Comment: Could you please explain what is "true probability space"?

Comment: @null When we do a statistical experiement, I assume we must have some "true" probability space that we are trying to  model when we do regression analysis/inference.

Comment: You assume that the probability measure assigns the entire space a probability of 1, and that the codomain of the measure is [0,1], and that the probability of a disjoint union is the sum of the probabilities. These assumptions are sufficient to satisfy the axioms of probability, beyond that the assumptions you put on it depend on what you are attempting to model.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a sample space must be equipped/equippable with a $\sigma$-algebra. Otherwise, the sample space is almost never important enough to consider at any further level of detail. There is no assumption of a "true" probability space; such a thing does not exist.

As an example: consider the experiment of flipping a coin.

**Option 1**: You could take your probability space to be $\Omega = \{H, T\}$, use the complete sigma algebra $2^{\Omega}$ and declare $\mathbb P(H) = \mathbb P(T) = 1/2$, and the coin flip variable could be $X(\omega) = \omega$.

**Option 2**: You could take your probability space to be $\Omega = [0, 1]$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, use Borel measure as $\mathbb P$, and the coin flip variable $X$ could map $[0, 1/2]$ to $H$ and map $[1/2, 1]$ to $T$.

Neither of these is more legitimate than the other. Either one does exactly what it is supposed to do, despite having entirely different topologies. One is countable (finite, in fact); the other, uncountable.

The technical assumptions made on the space are precisely those demanded by the definition: you need a $\sigma$-algebra and a measure that satisfies some specific properties. If you need to delve into the specifics of $\Omega$ for some problem (and again, this is **rarely** necessary), you can construct any space you want that satisfies the axioms and yields the probability distribution you want.